# Is eight is the most common number of divisors of integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

If the prime factorisation of a number is $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$ then the number of divisors of $n$ is $\tau_n = (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots(a_k+1)$. Thus number of divisors of a number is 2 if an only if the number is a prime. In other words, the number of integers $\le x$ that have exactly two divisors is equal to $\pi(x)$ the number of primes $\le x$.

Let $N_k(x)$ be the number of integers $\le x$ which have $k$ divisors. Thus for $x = 2000000$, $N_8(x) = 448777$ and $N_4(x) = 407091$. Is there an asymptotic formula for the number integers $\le x$ which have exactly $k$ divisors?

I observed that 8 is the most common number of divisors. More specifically, we have:

**Conjecture**:

> $N_8(x) > N_k(x)$ for all $x > 248770$ and $k \ne 8$.

or more elegantly:

> Eight is the most common number of divisors of integers.

I have verified this conjecture for $x = 2*10^{10}$.

**Question:** Can this conjecture be proved/disproved or is there any heuristic arguments against or in support of it?

Comment: what is $N_k$ exactly?

Comment: @SK19 $N_k$ is the number of integers $\le x$ which have $k$ divisors.

Comment: If I understand the notation correctly, then $N_3(x)=\pi(\sqrt x)$.

Comment: [This mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes) gives an estimate for the number of numbers less than $x$ with exactly $k$ distinct prime factors $$ \pi_k(x)\sim\frac{(\log\log x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \cdot \frac{x}{\log x} $$ I imagine $N_{2^k}$ should be closely related to $\pi_k$. I'm not sure if that relationship is asymptotically just a constant multiple or not.

Comment: @BarryCipra : $N_3(x) = $ No. of integers $\le x$ which are of the form $p^{2}$ where $p$ is a prime. Hence $N_3(x) = \pi(\sqrt x)$

Comment: Presumably you have checked your conjecture that $N_8(x)\gt N_{k\not=8}(x)$ for some range of values of $x$.  Can you tell us what that range is? I.e., when does the inequality kick in, and how high up have you checked?

Comment: There is nothing special about 8. Go higher, and eventually some other number will take over.

Comment: @IvanNeretin : OK. Any heuristics or theoretical arguments to support your statement or is it just a guess?

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha Let's say it is just a guess, but I feel pretty confident about it.

Comment: @BarryCipra : The inequality kicks for $x > 248770$.

Comment: A similar question is under discussion at MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342473/what-is-known-about-the-mode-of-the-number-of-divisors-le-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a number to have exactly 8 divisors, it must be of the form $p^7$, or $p^3q$, or $pqr$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes. The first two types are much rarer in the long run, so the count is dominated by the numbers of the form $pqr$.

It's probably not hard to prove that numbers of the form $pqrs$, with $p,q,r,s$ distinct primes, eventually outnumber numbers of the form $pqr$, and when that happens (or soon thereafter), numbers with 16 divisors will take over from numbers with 8 divisors.